# QMAKE. How to figure out host platform and target platform when cross compiling QT projects

Tags: qt, arm, cross-platform, qmake, qnx

I compiling for QNX, ARM, My Host platform can be Win32/64 ,  Linux  or Mac
I want to find a way to see wheat is my host platform in my PRO file (on computer I building my project)

Apparently using:

```
win32 {}
unix {}
macx {}
```

does not work because on different OSes it will always report unix, so I assume this is target platform
So what is the way to obtain current host platform to make PRO file flexible because on different platform I would like to do different things.

Thank you

Comment: Those are for the **target**, which is QNX/ARM.  You can look at the *HOST* variables in [configuring Qmake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html).  I don't know if the project files have conditional syntax for the host OS like you show for the target.  Try `message(Host: $$[QT_HOST_PREFIX])` for example.  Btw, I guess tag [tag:qt5] is relevant or are you on Qt4?

Comment: Sure it one of the options! I think $$[QMAKE_SPEC] would be a bit better in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could not get anything better then:

```
QMAKE_SPEC_T = $$[QMAKE_SPEC]

contains(QMAKE_SPEC_T,.*win32.*){
    HOST_PLATFORM=WIN
    IS_WIN = 1
}

contains(QMAKE_SPEC_T,.*macx.*){
    HOST_PLATFORM=MAC
    IS_MAC = 1
}

contains(QMAKE_SPEC_T,.*linux.*){
    HOST_PLATFORM=LINUX
    IS_LINUX = 1
}
```

and then anywhere to check:

```
!isEmpty(IS_WIN):message($${HOST_PLATFORM})
!isEmpty(IS_MAC):message($${HOST_PLATFORM})
!isEmpty(IS_LINUX):message($${HOST_PLATFORM})
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe `QMAKE_HOST` variable is the answer to your question?

Here's information from [official Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-host):

## QMAKE_HOST

Provides information about the host machine running qmake. For example, you can retrieve the host machine architecture from QMAKE_HOST.arch.

- .arch - Host architecture
- .os - Host OS
- .cpu_count - Number of available cpus
- .name - Host computer name
- .version - Host OS version number
- .version_string - Host OS version string

`win32-g++:contains(QMAKE_HOST.arch, x86_64):{
    message("Host is 64bit")
    ...
}`